# Excluding Schema in PHP Soap Connection

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am able to make requests and get responses in Soap UI, but am not even able to connect to my WSDL via PHP. I keep getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing Schema: can't import schema from 'http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime'
```

The schema in the error is excluded in both Soap UI's Proxy settings and WSDL settings.

[image]

[image]

How can I exclude this schema in PHP?
Here is my code right now:

```
$wsdl = $_POST["url"];
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl);
```